# SSIS remove carriage returns

Tags: c#, sql, import, ssis, carriage-return

I've a flat file which has 48 columns. The columns are tab delimited and the rows CR-LF (return).
Now I've the problem that there is a column which sometimes contains carriage returns and there is no possibility to change the file before the import process.

At the moment I wrote a C# script task which looks in every row, counts the tabs and when there is a return and the counted tabs are not divisible by 48 it deletes the return. This way works but it's to slow because my files are very big and with that way I've to read every character in the file.

Does someone knows a better way to get rid of these carriage returns?

Cheers!

Comment: is the column with CRLF surrounded by text qualified such as double quotes? Also which version of sql server you are using?

Comment: yes i just saw that the CRLF are surrounded by double quotes. The version is MS-SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I guess then you are out of luck since there is nothing for SSIS to help differentiate between CRLF in the field and CRLF at the end of row.

Comment: In that case, you can specify double quotes as Text Qualifier in SSIS to import them ignoring CRLF in the field value

Answer (score -1):

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2130093-ssis-package-flat-file-destination-blank-row-at-end-of-file

```
    public void Main()
    {
        string filename = @"C:\Temp\Gerard.txt";
        string fileinfo = "";
        string curline = "";

        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(filename);
        while ((curline = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (fileinfo != "")
            {
                fileinfo = fileinfo + Environment.NewLine;
            }

            fileinfo = fileinfo + curline;
        }
        tr.Close();

        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(filename, false);
        tw.Write(fileinfo);
        tw.Close();

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain how this answers the original question. As far as I can see, this code just copies the input file in an inefficient manner. Reading lines one at a time then concatenating them into one big string seems very ineffecient. Concatenating big files into big strings will likely cause lots of allocating and disposing of strings and lots of calls of the garbage collector. Nothing is done to sort out the unexpected CRs.

Comment: After consulting master Roshi, the code above works, but only with files that are not considerably containing large amounts of data. As far as explaining how this answers the original question, it does so by removing the last unwanted line from the file. Or do you want me to explain how the code works?

Comment: Deleting the last line is not what is wanted. The question wants multiple carriage returns deleted from throughout the file. I cannot see how your code deletes the last line of the file, it appears to just copy the input without any changes.